# Where do I put my WebSocket code and how to pass its data to a template

Tags: ember.js

I have a small application that I want to try to implement using Ember.js, but I'm not really sure what the best way to do it is.

The application is just supposed to take bids from a user and when a countdown reaches 0, it prints out that the highest bidder has won.

I'm wondering where to put the code for my WebSocket that receives data from a server and how to pass the data received to the template. I read that the data should be passed in the route's model, but I'm not sure how.

Right now I actually have implemented most of it, but most of the html is just put into my index.hbs file, and then I do all the logic with the websockets and changing the values of the html elements inside a script tag also in index.hbs. This just feels like a terrible way to do it, so I would like to know how to utilize some of the features of Ember.js to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a a service like sockets.js, call (example) `sockets.connect()` in initializer or in application route, controller (the point is that you connect to sockets when your application is ready).

Then your sockets should push payload they receive to store. Or refresh models (like Bid) on changes stream (when you get only notification that something change from Web Sockets).

For me it seems that you have little-to-no knowledge of Ember if you put JavaScript into `<script>` tag. I think you should also learn how to architect your application and divide logic, or how to create global logic for whole application - like sockets.